# Why does UPDATE id_order_state = 4 modifies all the field?

Tags: mysql

I am new with MYSQL and I am having trouble with this code:

```
UPDATE gf_order_history
   SET date_add = 
     ( SELECT delivery_date 
         FROM gf_orders
        WHERE gf_order_history.id_order = gf_orders.id_order 
          AND gf_order_history.id_order_state = 4);
```

When I execute this code all the fields in `id_order_state = 4` has been well updated but all the rest `id_order_state` which are different from 4 has been replaced to 0 .

Do you have any ideas what did I do wrong ?
All I want is the field `id_order_state = 4` only to be updated.

Thank you very much for your help,

Sincerely,

Cyril

Comment: What have you tried to check why this happens? Why not remove everything within the brackets to see how the query would look like?

Comment: It's often useful to start with the SELECT that returns the expected result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a where in your update query

```
UPDATE gf_order_history
   SET date_add = 
     ( SELECT delivery_date 
         FROM gf_orders
        WHERE gf_order_history.id_order = gf_orders.id_order )
WHERE gf_order_history.id_order_state = 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works !!! I have spent so many times to solve it,  I did not know I could use 2 Where in the same query !! Thank you again :))))

Comment: It is not 2 where in the same query, as it is a query with a subquery. Your subquery has a where, your update query as well.